# how to access soap service through javaScript?

Tags: javascript, soap

I have a requirement to access Soap service through JavaScript.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts', true);

            // build SOAP request
           var sr= '<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ts="http://ts.ch01/">'+
  ' <x:Header/>'+
  ' <x:Body>'+
       '<ts:getAsTimeElapsed/>'+
    '</x:Body>'+
'</x:Envelope>'
alert(sr);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        // alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                    }
                }
            }
            // Send the POST request
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts/action');
            xmlhttp.send(sr);
            // send request
            // ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html> <!-- typo -->
```

while I am trying above code getting below warning message/error and not getting any response.

in back end (java)
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler handleExchange
WARNING: Cannot handle HTTP method: OPTIONS

in front end --
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Could you please help me for this.  any suggestions please.

Note:  The above code works in IE and not in Edge browser.

Comment: A warning is not an error

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks for your great response as a comment.